# Should I use .NET Core or .NET 5?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-standard, .net-5

I will soon embark into writing a new component for my organization that will primarily targeted for windows machines. However, in future it may be used on Linux systems as well.

1. Given the emergence of .NET 5, is there any point of writing it in .NET core?
2. I see that .NET Core 3.1 in LTS but not sure about .NET 5. Is .NET 5 in a state that make it suitable for use in production applications?
3. Also, should .NET standard play any role in this decision making process?

Comment: Spoilers: .NET 5 *is* .NET Core, they just rebranded it.

Comment: Use .Net 5 if you can. And aim to make as many assemblies .Net Standard as possible for maximum portability. Once .Net 6 is out, it will likely be trivial to update your assemblies to it.

Comment: i recommend reading up on what the different .net-versions actually _are_. then your question will answer itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It mainly depends on what features you require and what targets your library needs to support.

The lowest target from those mentioned is **.NET Standard 2.0**. Such a library is fully compatible with any **.NET Core, .NET 5 but even .NET Framework 4.8** - so for backwards compatibility it is a good choice. .NET Standard 2.1 is no longer compatible with FW 4.8, but has many additional runtime features that were introduced with .NET Core 3.1 and is compatible with .NET Core 3.1 up (including .NET 5+).

However, you can target .NET Core or .NET 5 directly. In these cases your library will work with that version of .NET Core or higher. Note that **.NET 5 is essentially just rebranded .NET Core**, so it is still fully compatible.

**.NET 5 is production ready**, only not LTS - from now on the even versions of .NET will be LTS, so .NET 6, .NET 8, etc. New versions will be released yearly. If you want the latest and greatest features, you can target the latest .NET. But you can target older versions and still use your library in the newer ones without any issues as long as you don't require some newer APIs.

Answer (score 2):

There are several things in play here. .Net Core 3.1 is an LTS as you say and .Net 5 is not. The next LTS release will be .Net 6 in november/december this year.

Based on that maybe you should use .Net Core 3.1 then, but on the other hand it is only supported about 8 months longer then what .Net 5 will be and the upgrade path from .Net 5 to .Net 6 will probably be smaller. So based on this you will need to decide on your own.

You can see more about the support policy over at Microsoft: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core